# Change logging in AspNetCore host while running

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, kestrel

Is it possible to change logging level on an AspNetCore 2.2 web host that is already started? In particular I am hosting my API within an application, using the following:

```
 IWebHost host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace))
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls($"http://0.0.0.0:{Constants.ApiPort}", $"http://localhost:{Constants.ApiPort}")
                .Build();
```

Ideally I could call ConfigureLogging again and change the LogLevel or do other things as I can when I'm working with the various "builders" before it is built. Would I need a third-party logging provider or can it be done with the standard Microsoft logging?